# Could I use one ckeditor component to edit multiple small fields at once?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor very successfully in a training application for the authoring of course content, where each course has several chapters. Each chapter has a main body of HTML text, and a list of questions at the end of the chapter. Right now, the questions are editable only in plain text, but I would like to provide course authors with a bit more control here. It has crossed my mind to use something like MarkDown, but now it crosses my mind that I might be able to persuade ckeditor, with some JavaScript voodoo on my side, so handle several target text areas at once. Maybe switch it's target text area when the user changes focus between questions? Could I do something like this? Has anyone tried before? Questions are generally short text, so I don't want a whole ckeditor shebang for each question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a shared toolbar as shown in the sharedspaces example http://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/ckeditor/_samples/sharedspaces.html

You just need to adjust a minimal toolbar for those small fields and a javascript to move the toolbar location as needed (or whatever solution you can think of that you like)